# Eliminate $\theta$ from these two equations

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

> If $$\operatorname{cosec}\theta-\operatorname{sin}\theta=m$$ and $$\operatorname{sec}\theta-\operatorname{cos}\theta=n$$ then eliminate $\theta$.

My work:

Squaring both the equations and then adding them will yeild $$\operatorname{cosec}^2\theta+\operatorname{sec}^2\theta=m^2+n^2+3$$ or
$$\operatorname{cos}^2\theta\operatorname{sin}^2\theta=\frac{1}{m^2+n^2+3}$$ or$$\operatorname{sin}^2 2\theta=\frac{4}{m^2+n^2+3}$$ or
$$\theta=\frac12\cdot\operatorname{arcsin}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2+3}}\right)$$
Now to eliminate $\theta$, we will have to put its value in any of the two equations.

But actually I don't know how to evaluate inverse trigonometric values, like that of $\theta$ in terms of $m$ and $n$. And after that I guess it will be difficult to simplify the expression.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Keep your sights on $\sin^2 \theta+\cos^2 \theta=1$. Start with looking at $m-n$ and $mn$. It helps to recall $a^2+b^2 = (a+b)^2-2ab$

Comment: Actually you solved the given problem, if n,m are given numerical values you could determine $\Theta$

Comment: @trula $m$ and $n$ are not given

Comment: Putting back the result into the original equations will just leave trivial equations (provided your calculation is correct).  So there is no point in putting the values back, except for double-checking the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing  $x$ for $\theta,$

$$m=\csc x-\sin x=\dfrac{\cos^2x}{\sin x}$$

$$\text{Similarly, } n=\sec x-\cos x=\dfrac{\sin^2x}{\cos x}$$

$$\dfrac mn=\dfrac{\cos^3x}{\sin^3x} \implies\dfrac m{\cos^3x}=\dfrac n{\sin^3x}=\dfrac{m^{2/3}+n^{2/3}}1$$

Replacing the values of $\cos x,\sin x;$

$$ m=\dfrac{\left(\dfrac m{m^{2/3}+n^{2/3}}\right)^{2/3}}{\left(\dfrac n{m^{2/3}+n^{2/3}}\right)^{1/3}} \implies m(m^{2/3}+n^{2/3})^{1/3}n^{1/3}=m^{2/3}$$

Now I leave the rest for the OP

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved the question.

From the equations we can conclude that $$mn=\operatorname{sin}\theta \operatorname{cos}\theta$$
or $$\theta=\frac12\cdot\operatorname{arcsin}(2mn)$$ so it is seen
$$2mn=\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2+3}}\right)$$ or
$$m^2n^4+n^2m^4+3m^2n^2(1)=1$$
$$m{^\frac{2}{3}}n{^\frac{4}{3}}+m{^\frac{4}{3}}n{^\frac{2}{3}}=1$$

Comment: It can be solved without using arcfunctions. Multiplying gives: $m^2n=\cos^3 \theta$, $n^2m=\sin^3 \theta$, then $\cos^2 \theta = (m^2n)^{2/3}$, $\sin^2\theta=(n^2m)^{2/3}$, then $(m^2n)^{2/3}+(n^2m)^{2/3}=1$